# Set background opacity for parent, but not its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, opacity

I thought I wanted to something fairly simple but it turns out its not simple.

I have a  with a child <span> element. I want to be able to set (using javascript/jquery), the opacity of the <div>'s background but not the text within it. The color of the div is user-provided and could be either a HEX value or a named color.

**Idea 1**: use rgba(). This would be fine if I could only set the alpha but I can't. So I would need to check if the provided value is a hex or a named color and convert it to rgb values, which seems like way too much hassle for a simple problem.

**Idea 2**: prevent the span from inheriting the opacity value from its parent. But appearently the opacity isn't inherited. It is just applied on the whole DOM element and its children as if it were one element.

**Idea 3**:
Create a seperate div just for the background color and make it a sibling of the span element. This would probably work but in my opinion is a ridiculous solution. Also when I tried that, I ran into a problems which forced me to apply css settings like `position: absolute;` to my span and div. Which I didn't want to as it broke other styling I had applied. Maybe it is possible, but its such an ugly solution.

Is there really no other way to do this?

Comment: when you get the applied style, it will be in rgba form; you can adjust the alpha independent from the color.

Comment: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm

Comment: I've made it work only with the Idea #3. Although I don't get it why do you need absolute position for <span>? If parent div is relative - sibling div is absolute and top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 then span can be relative?

Comment: As NemanjaSRB said, no need for position:absolute for both -> children and container... Here is one simple trick, based on idea 3, which, actually, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tgdjbdv3/ (absolute position just for cloned child - span)